# Getting ERROR 4010 when trying to run Pig through Java

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'm trying to run a Pig script through Java. Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, InterruptedException, IOException {    
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://<some-value>:8020");
    props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "<some-value>:54311");
    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);

    Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("INPUT_PATH", "hdfs://<some-input-value>");
    params.put("OUTPUT_FILE", "hdfs:///user/<some-username>/last-login-out");

    pigServer.registerScript("last-login-by-userid.pig", params);
}
```

But whenever I run the program, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 4010: Cannot find hadoop configurations in classpath (neither hadoop-site.xml nor core-site.xml was found in the classpath). If you plan to use local mode, please put -x local option in command line.
```

I've moved the `pig-0.10.1` folder that I downloaded from the Apache website into `Applications` and have added `export PIG_HOME=/Applications/pig-0.10.1` in my `~/.bash_profile`.

When I log into the `<some-value>:8020` server, I'm able to run the Pig script just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your hadoop installation?  On my system, the configuration is under `/etc/hadoop/conf`.  Add this to the classpath of your Java program.

For example, for various reasons, I don't use the installed `pig` bash script; I just call Pig's `Main` class like this:

```
java -cp /path/to/pig-0.10.0.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf org.apache.pig.Main`
```

Comment: I downloaded Hadoop from `http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-1.0.4.tar.gz` and moved the folder into `Applications`. I run my program via Eclipse. My `.bash_profile` has these two lines `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java:$JAVA_HOME` and `export PIG_HOME=/Applications/pig-0.10.1`

Comment: I don't know how your machine is set up. You'll have to find the hadoop configuration directory. Look around your `Applications` folder.

Comment: Okay, I got around this issue by installed `hadoop` and `pig` through `brew` and then copying the `core-site.xml` file into my classpath of my Java project. Now, I'm getting some other error when I try to run the program. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same exception while running Pig from Java. This has been resolved after adding path of hadoop conf directory to the project property libraries add jar/folder

Ref: http://helpmetocode.blogspot.in/2012/04/exception-in-thread-main.html

Thanks,

Kalai